# Word for 'getting removed from Hot Network Question'

Tags: word-request, verbs

When a question becomes a [**Hot Network Question**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/what-does-became-hot-network-question-mean), it attracts so many views. I have noticed that after few days of becoming hot, the question loses its effect and slowly "......"es from Hot Network Question. I need a word in the blank whose meaning should be "getting removed".

How can I say that? Is there a word for that?

> the question is now **".....ing"** from Hot Network Question

Comment: Perhaps disappear?

Comment: Work your way through [synonyms of ***recede***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/recede)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *to fade*? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fade) lists various definitions that might apply, e.g. "to sink away" (because it literally sinks down [the list](https://stackexchange.com/)).

I would use the plural for questions, though:

> The question is now fading from the Hot Network Questions.

[*to recede*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recede) may also fit.